# Window resize to fixed point

Tags: jquery, html, windows, resize, width

I am working on to fix the minimum width for  the window on resize by using the below script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
       var pageWidth=$(window).width(); 
       if(pageWidth <= 320){
           alert(pageWidth);                
           $(window).width(320);
       }    
   });
});
```

In my window i dont want it to be be resized below 320px; The above script is not working correctly. Whats the mistake i am making here.

Comment: What is not working ? can you check it here, http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/xUd4U/

Comment: The problem is i cant able to increase my window size after reaching 320px;

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, you cannot prevent the user to resize his browser :)

If you have a fluid page, you can only set at a certain point a fixed width to your (e.g.) `body`, but not to the `window` it self. In any case, the user will still be able to resize the browser window.

Comment: @VivekDragon sure, the alert, but not that thing you want.

Comment: Thats right i tried to resume the the resize() after the certain point is fixed

Comment: If you are interested please look into this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/14064942/1716774